# Android Studio - Copy & Paste Issue regarding whitespace

Tags: android-studio, whitespace, indentation, paste

When I try to paste code off some webiste (e.g. Android official tutorial) some space characters(usually the ones used as indents) are shown as illegal characters and generates error(with red lines under them).

It didn't happen when I was using Windows 7 or macOS, but only happens in Windows 10, if I remember right.

Please let me know if there's any solution for this problem.

**Update**
Here's the screenshot. I copy and pasted some Java code in a random Android tutorial webpage - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

[image]

Comment: Can you post SCREEN-SHOT of it?